# Realizar a Média de coluna valor dentro de uma tabela com R

Tags: r

Estou precisando gerar a média em uma coluna de valor de uma tabela no R, porem não estou conseguindo. Eu já fiz assim criando um vetor:

```
x <- c(15,12,8,9,5,6,1,2)
mean(x)
```

Ele funciona, porém quando aponto para a tabela que gerei dentro do R não consigo:

```
x <- (receitas_vs_depesas_contratadas_tidy %>%
  select.list(VR_TOTAL_RECEITA))%>%

mean(x)

erro:Error in (receitas_vs_depesas_contratadas_tidy %>% select.list(VR_TOTAL_RECEITA)) %>%  : 
  could not find function "%>%"
```

Comment: Carregue o pacote `dplyr` ou `tidyverse` para ter acesso ao comando `%>%`. Depois disso, o comando `(receitas_vs_depesas_contratadas_tidy %>% select.list(VR_TOTAL_RECEITA))%>%` vai continuar dando erro. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Edite a sua pergunta com os detalhes necessários para que possamos te ajudar da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: importei o pacote e mudei o código:

Comment: media<-c(receitas_vs_depesas_contratadas_tidy %>%
  select(VR_TOTAL_DESPESA)%>%
  mutate(media=mean(VR_TOTAL_DESPESA)))

Comment: mas ainda não resolveu

Comment: Por isso postei o link acima. Se não tivermos uma parte que seja do teu conjunto de dados, vamos ficar aqui tateando no escuro sem chegar a conclusão alguma. Edite a sua pergunta para deixá-la reproduzível. Vai ser mais trabalhoso no começo, mas todos que estão aqui vão poupar seu tempo, inclusive tu mesmo.

Comment: Se quer só a média da coluna com o pacote `dplyr` nem é preciso o `select`. Veja este exemplo com o conjunto de dados `iris` que vem com o R base. `iris %>% summarise(media = mean(Sepal.Length))`. Note que é `summarise`, não é `mutate`.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o `summarise_all` do pacote `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
x <- c(15,12,8,9,5,6,1,2)

df <- data.frame(x,
                 y = rnorm(length(x)),
                 w = rnorm(length(x)))

df %>% 
  dplyr::summarise_all(mean)
```

```
> df %>% 
+   dplyr::summarise_all(mean)
     x         y          w
1 7.25 0.1314544 0.05200928
```

Perceba que a resposta das médias é igual a média de cada coluna, quando utilizado o `$`.

```
mean(df$x)
#
> mean(df$x)
[1] 7.25
```

```
mean(df$y)
#
> mean(df$y)
[1] 0.1314544
```

```
mean(df$w)
#
> mean(df$w)
[1] 0.05200928
```